# clojure.data.xml and parsing jdbc xml object

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I'm attempting to read xml (actual xml type) from a postgres database in clojure, however i'm not sure how to cast the `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4SQLXML` object to something `clojure.data.xml` can make sense of.

When running `(xml/parse  ...)` on this object i'm getting the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: createXMLStreamReader for class com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)
```

code below:

```
(ns clj-xml-dbms.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as j]
            [clojure.data.xml :as xml]
            [clj-xml-dbms.core :refer :all])
  (:use [clojure.pprint ] ))

(def db-spec {
             :classname "org.postgres.Driver"
             :subprotocol "postgres"
             :subname "//localhost:5432/mydb"
             :user "me"
             :password "secret"
             })

;; get the results of a query
(def results
  (let [
        sql "select row_id, xml_col from stg.some_table limit 1 "
        db-connection (j/get-connection db-spec )
        statement (j/prepare-statement db-connection sql)
        query-results (j/query db-connection [statement]) ]
    (first query-results)))

(pprint results)
;; {:row_id 18627,
;;  :xml_col #object[org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4SQLXML 0x6897f635 "org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4SQLXML@6897f635"]}

;; obviously clojure.data.xml/parse isn't going to work on that:
(xml/parse (:xml_col results))

;; IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: createXMLStreamReader for class com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)
```

I guess i could cast the xml type in the db to a string, but there has to be something cleaner that that i would think.  Any tips appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since XML *is* a string, you may have to do exactly that. What does `(String) results` look like?

Comment: Looking at [Javadoc](https://javadocs.com/docs/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1004-jdbc4/org/postgresql/jdbc4/Jdbc4SQLXML.java) of `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4SQLXML`, it seems like `(xml/parse (.getBinaryStream (:xml_col results)))` or `(xml/parse (.getString (:xml_col results)))` may work

Comment: For me, `(xml/parse (.getString (:xml_col results)))` did the trick.  If you post as an answer i'll mark correct?  or i'll do it in a few days if you don't want the points.  thanks.

Comment: Before writing an answer I reviewed the source code of clojure.data.xml and I do not understand why it works for you. In theory, it should be either `(xml/parse (.getBinaryStream (:xml_col results)))` or `(xml/parse-str (.getString (:xml_col results)))`. `xml/parse` takes either a Reader or an InputStream. `xml/parse-str` takes a String.